# How do I paint to a non-.Net host window from a C# DLL?

Tags: c#, delphi, window, draw, handle

I have an application in Delphi 6, and due to library issues, I need to write a component in C# or C++ that will exist on a Delphi form. The program is currently Delphi and C#, and it calls C# for dialogs. I need something embedded into a TForm that will allow me to draw that component in C#.

I think I can create a component in Delphi and during its `Paint` routine I just call the function in the DLL. But what do I pass to the C# DLL so that it can paint in that window, and how would I get C# to actually do it?

I guess just being able to paint in some arbitrary DC on demand in C# is all I need to do.

Comment: If you want to answer your own question do so in an answer. Not in the question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's great that you've found the answer to your question, but please put it in the "answer" section below. To do that, begin by clicking the "edit" link below your question. Select and cut everything below the "Solved" line, and then save your edits. Finally, click the "Answer Your Question" button at the bottom of the page and paste your answer there. Then you can get the [self-learner badge](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/14/self-learner), and after some time, you can mark your answer as the "accepted" answer.

Comment: Seems reasonable.  Done.

Comment: I left the question open for about 3 hours in edit mode as I was making sure it was a good clear question.  Then I stumbled upon the answer, while forming the question.  "Ask a duck", they say.  So I pasted it in there.  It's proper now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C#

```
public static void DoIt(IntPtr srcWindow)
{
Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(srcWindow);
g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red), new Point(0, 0), new Point(400, 400));
}
```

Delphi:

```
type
    intPtrArgs = procedure(hand : hwnd); StdCall;

procedure T_CS.RePaint;  //extends TWinControl
var
  Hm: HModule;
  ExtDoIt: intptrArgs;  
begin
  Hm := LoadLibrary(pchar('my.dll'));
  try
    @ExtDoIt := GetProcAddress(Hm, 'DoIt');
    ExtDoIt(Handle);
  finally
    FreeLibrary(Hm);
  end;
end;
```

It's silly to load an unload on each paint, but for example purposes it works.

For anyone else trying to do this, you will need to google "Reverse P/Invoke" to be able to see the C# DLL procedure in another language.

Example Reverse P/Invoke
http://www.blong.com/Conferences/BorConUK2002/Interop1/Win32AndDotNetInterop.htm